# Comedy: Human-like aliens disintegrate a football (soccer) referee in the middle of the game

Tags: story-identification, movie

This could be an american movie. 
I watched it in Venezuela.
There was a group of human-like aliens. 
I think they were four (4) aliens that acted as the Madagascar penguins, with one as the leader.
They were watching a football game and they didn't understand much. 
Hearing the people yell something like "Referee, why don't you die?", one of the alien kept watching the referee, concentrated and... the referee disappeared in a explosion, leaving out only his clothes. ***That's the only thing they disintegrate in this movie***. They wore dark shirts and shorts as if themselves were football players. They were friendly (though I guess the referee wouldn't agree)

I saw this movie in black and white in the early 70's so it could be anytime before.

Comment: Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't even know if you'll be able to see this, but this sounds like '[***El futbolista fenomeno***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0283353/)' (The Phenomenal Footballer). It's part of a series of movies starring Mexican comedian [Adalberto Martinez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adalberto_Mart%C3%ADnez) (AKA "Resortes") where he becomes successful at various sports.

In this one, **4 humanoid aliens (one of whom is the leader) help Resortes become a great football player, and you can see in the clip below how they watch and influence a football match with their alien magic** and help him win (the aliens themselves appear at 01:30 & 05:30). This Mexican comedy is from the *late* 70s, though.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. This is not the movie. (very hilarious, thou)
Thanks for your efforts.